# Duplicating array with frozen elements

Tags: ruby

I am trying to duplicate the ARGV array to remove the frozen status of each element but nothing I do seems to work.

All other posts I can find on the subject suggest that using .dup should work however it isn't. Here is how I have used it:

```
args = ARGV.dup
puts args[0].frozen?
    => true

i = 0
argv.each {|x| 
           args[i] = x.dup
           i += 1 }
puts args[0].frozen?
     => true
```

I have also tried using the assign operator and clone method in these scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and got the following:

```
args = ARGV.dup
p args[0].frozen? #=> true

args.each_with_index {|arg,i| args[i] = arg.dup }
p args[0].frozen? #=> false
```

Basically this should suffice:

```
args = ARGV.map(&:dup)
p args[0].frozen? #=> false
```

Comment: I think you meant ARGV.each_with_index, and that still left the elements frozen for me.

However the .map suggestion works great! Thanks for your help. And also thanks for showing me the each_with_index method, that will be handy!